# Отличия между attr() и getAttribute()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую скрипт, который в теле колбека при вызове this возвращает DOM:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему я могу получить значение атрибута `id` div-блока при помощи `getAttribute()` и не могу при помощи `attr()`? Эти две функции делают не одно и то же?

Comment: У вас подключены какие библиотеки? Просто я не припомню attr в стандартном js

Comment: `getAttribute` - `javascript`, `attr` - `jquery`, соответственно второй работает с jquery-обьектами, а первый с обычными ДОМ-обьектами

Answer (score 1):

Отличия между `attr()` и `getAttribute()` в основном в тому что `attr()` ето функция библиотеки `jquery`, которая работает с jquer-ным обьектом (который является какой-то оберткой над стандартным дом обьектом). `getAttribute()` в свою очередь стандартный `js` метод, и он работает с дом обьектами, а с jquer-ным обьектом естественно не сработает, так как у етого обьекта нету такого метода, по той-же причине `attr()` не сработает с обычным обьектом.

Вот маленькая иллюстрация :

```js
var jqueryA = $('#a');
var jsA = document.querySelector('#a');

console.log(jqueryA.attr('data-test'));
try {
  console.log(jqueryA.getAttribute('data-test'));
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
//
console.log(jsA.getAttribute('data-test'));
try {
  console.log(jsA.attr('data-test'));
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-test="123" id="a"></div>
```